# ButtonClick in DropDown not working in VS2010/Outlook2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, outlook-addin

I'm working on an add-in for Outlook 2010.  I've created a new Ribbon Tab with a dropdown box.  I'd like for the data in the dropdown to update when I click the dropdown button, but nothing is occurring.  I've written the sample code below for testing purposes and nothing fires:

```
        private void dropDown1_ButtonClick(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Dropdown CLick");
    }
```

This is as simple as it gets, but nothing is firing.  Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?  The only other code that exists in this ribbon right now is what loads the data.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding

```
private void dropDown1_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Dropdown CLick");
}
```

is what you wanna do.  No where did I see ButtonClick as the proper tag.

Comment: That's what comes up as a valid action on the lightning bolt in VS2010.  Let me double check and get back to you.

Comment: Nope...Click is not an option...only ButtonClick.  I've even tried manually adding it rather than following the lightning bolt.

Comment: I've decided to go with a ComboBox instead.  That seems to be accomplishing what I need.  Thanks for the assistance.